# Find out which view controller segued to another

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

Hi I am writing a program and I ran into a problem. I have 4 view controllers. Vc1, Vc2, and Vc3 modal segue to Vc4. I was wondering how to find out which View controller segued to Vc4. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `presentingViewController` relationship should be setup between the 2 view controllers automatically so you just need to query the property from the presented view controller.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you a check right now. I can't give one until 9 min.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique, a 9 minute delay isn't something you should worry about and feel you need to apologise for :-)